# How to add submit event to dynamically generated form?

Tags: jquery

Here is the PHP code that generates the form:
form.php

```
 <?php
    echo '
    <form action="/wall/comment.php" method="post" id="submit-comment-form" name="'.$postid.'"> 
    <div class="write-comment-profile-pic">
    <img src= "'.$myprofilepic.'" width="30" height="30""/>
    </div>
    <div class="write-comment-textbox-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="textbox4" id="write-comment-textbox" value="Write a comment..." name="comment" style="width:65%;" />
    </div>
   </form>
   ';
   ?>
```

Jquery code which gets the form.php

```
$('#images img').click(function() { 
$.get('form.php', function(data) {
$('#image-pop-up').html(data);
});
});
```

AND here is the jquery code to needs to submit the form:

```
$('#image-pop-up').on('submit', '#submit-comment-form', function() { 
evt.preventDefault();       
});
```

in index.html image-pop-up div is an empty one 
just

`<div id="image-pop-up">`

```
</div>
```

this isn't working... what's wrong? how to fix it?

Comment: where is your submit ?

Comment: is #submit-comment-form wrapped in #image-pop-up? your code implies this, please show rendered markup for both of these

Comment: Is image-pop-up is a dialog?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  yea #submit-comment-form is wrapped by #image-pop-up

Comment: @BhushanFirake yep, #image-pop-up is a pop-up dialog.... inside which, jquery dynamically generates the form....

The form doesn't have a submit button it's submitted by pressing Enter key... but when i do this... the page loads up comment.php

Comment: So submit the dialog instead...please show your code it's hard to guess anything without that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect the problem is to do with selectors, and the targeted elements either not being found, or being the right elements to target.

A few things that could be wrong:

1. Double ID references is unnecessary: it's just another potential place to go wrong.
2. If `#image-pop-up` hasn't been generated when this code is executed, the event will never be bound.
3. The `submit` event only fires on forms, so you need to make sure that's what you're targeting.
4. You call `preventDefault()` of `evt`, but `evt` hasn't bound to the events argument.

Presuming that `#submit-comment-form` is the form you're dealing with, the following code should work regardless of whether any of the elements are available when it executes:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#submit-comment-form', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, can you mark it as an answer please? ;)

Comment: @Barney  +1 Great Explanation. I know this but i forgot. Thanks for remembering it.