# jQuery: can not submit form on dynamically loaded content - .click does not work

Tags: jquery

I have a comments page and below each comment there is a form to post subcomment using Jquery:

```
    <div class="commentcontainer" id="commentload0-<?php echo $kid;?>-3">
-----------------comments go here------------------
</div>

    <div class="commentupdate2" id="commentbox0-28-3" style="display:none">
     <div class="stcommenttext3">
<form action="" method="post" name="0-28-3"><input name="wh" id="wh" value="1" type="hidden">
<textarea name="comment" id="ctextarea0-28-3" onkeyup="textar1(this)" class="tarea2 expta"></textarea>
<input value="Save" id="0-28-3" class="subcoment_a button" style="vertical-align:top" type="submit"></form>
     </div></div>


<div class="comment_ui2" id="view0-<?php echo $kid;?>-3">
<a href="#" class="subcomments" vid="0-<?php echo $kid;?>-3" id="0-<?php echo $kid;?>-3">Load more comments</a></div>


$(".subcoment_a").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var ID = element.attr("id");
var comment = $("#ctextarea"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&msg_id=' + ID;
if(comment=='') {
alert("Incomplete form");
} else {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/save-comment.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#commentload"+ID).append(html);
$("#ctextarea"+ID).val('');
$("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
}
 });
}
return false;
});
```

Everything works so far.

But then I click on "Load more comments" and dynamically load next comments _forms (again using Jquery). If I enter text in a dynamically loaded form, I can not submit form using Jquery. The page does not call the script but refreshes itself.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add submit event to dynamically generated form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832534/how-to-add-submit-event-to-dynamically-generated-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
$(document.body).on('click', ".subcoment_a", function(){
```

The click event will thus be delegated to `".subcoment_a"` elements even if the're not present when you do the binding.